# Which Win32 function must I use to copy a file to a smartphone folder?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file, winapi

Using WindowsForms technology, I'm trying to copy a file that is locally stored on the hard drive (C:\) to a folder stored on a connected smartphone device via USB.

The folder "path" is represented using friendly names as `MyPCName\MyName\Card\Android` in the Explorer navigation bar, and as `::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#6&612ff8b&1&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{20002,SECZ9519043CHOHB01,31426543616}\{01A00139-011B-0124-3301-29011C013501}` internally in Windows.

I obtained that "internal path" by using the COM **[Shell.BrowseForFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065(v=vs.85).aspx)** method then checking the **[FolderItem.Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787844(v=vs.85).aspx)** property of the returned object.

Then after getting the path I tried both the **[CopyFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx)** and **[CopyFileEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363852(v=vs.85).aspx)** Win32 functions to copy the file but they didn't work. They seemed to be unable to recognize the directory path.

The syntax I used was like this:

```vb
Dim dirPath As String = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_04e8&pid_6860&ms_comp_mtp&samsung_android#6&612ff8b&1&0000#{6ac27878-a6fa-4155-ba85-f98f491d4f33}\SID-{20002,SECZ9519043CHOHB01,31426543616}\{01A00139-011B-0124-3301-29011C013501}"
NativeMethods.CopyFile("C:\MyFile.ext", dirPath & "\MyFile.ext", failIfExists:=True)
```

In that code the `CopyFile()` function returns **False** and the `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` function returns a **0x3** Win32 error code.

The CopyFile/CopyFileEx definitions I used were the same as those published on the Pinvoke.net website (C# versions):

- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/CopyFile.html
- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.copyfileex

---

If a user can copy the file just dragging it from an Explorer instance to the smartphone directory, then I think it is obvious that this can be reproduced programmatically just finding and using the same Win32 functions that Windows uses itself to perform that kind of copy operation from the UI side. Then what am I doing wrong? Why can CopyFile/CopyFileEx not copy the file? And how can I copy it?

Note that I'm looking for a solution written in C# or else VB.NET that can be solved just using managed code or else employing unmanaged code P/Invoking the Win32 functions, except the usage of COM libraries like the Shell COM objects (that provides a `CopyHere()` method). I would like to learn and to understand how I could do this kind of file copy operation using the Win32 API members.

Comment: When you open the sd card folder in Explorer, [shift-right click](http://superuser.com/q/582980/52365) a file and click Copy as path, what kind of path do you get in the clipboard?

Comment: @GSerg It seems the CopyAsPath shell extension doesn't work for this kind of devices, or at least for this specific device, the "Copy as path" option in the context-menu is not shown like it is shown for normal (hard drive)folders. Thanks for comment

Comment: Well, you can also try [Procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor). Set the filter to the explorer process and see what it calls and with which parameters.

Comment: CopyFile/CopyFileEx only work on actual files and directories, i.e., a real file system, visible to the kernel either because it is mounted locally or as a network drive.  You're dealing with a Shell folder, which is a virtual object that only exists inside the Shell's namespace.  The kernel doesn't know anything about it.  The Shell COM objects are the correct way to deal with this, I'm not sure why you're trying to avoid them.  You could try SHFileOperation I guess but this is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the Windows Portable Devices API.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388998(v=vs.85).aspx

Edit: I have successfully used this API, using COM Interop in C#, to read/write files on my Android Galaxy S3.

You can also find good information about using this API in C# at the following blog: https://github.com/geersch/WPD

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have referenced the related WPD COM libraries in my .NET project but really I have no idea about how to list devices, select the desired one and finally copy files to one of its folders. Also the MSDN samples are only for C++ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd798115(v=vs.85).aspx and the existing samples in C# in sites like CodePlex or GirHub are very big general projects hat covers much more things that transfering files, or in other words: a painful of analysis for an unexperienced user in WPD. Anyways I'm checking it to try understand..

Comment: I don't think this advice is correct. The OS should be (and is) able to abstract device API away when copying files over.

Comment: Please explain how this advice in "incorrect" or "poor". Either you offer an alternative to the WPD-API or you keep such unconstructive criticism to yourself.
Our research conclucded that there is literally no other way to do this, but to use the mentioned (very clunky) API. There is a strong indication that even the the OS or explorer are using exactly this API, when working with such devices.